# Seeking HTML5 video at a particular position in a web page

Tags: django, html

Following code is working but it is not starting the video from 3 seconds on my page

```
<video id="vid1" width="320" height="240" controls>
<source src="iphone16.mp4#t=3,9" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

I am using Django for development of my web application. Any idea why it's not working in my case??

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you need to set the currentTime property.

Link to a tutorial => http://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_prop_currenttime.asp

Comment: @kkaosninja i used this method as well but still its not working in my environment 
any other idea